# Changing the background of body by switching classes during specific interval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have already scoped the internet carefully but can only find out how to rectify this problem using javascript, but I am solely using jQuery in this code.

What I am doing is adding a class every 600 milliseconds that changes the background-image of the body of an html file, but I need this to go on forever.

```
$("body").addClass("mountain-1");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").addClass("mountain-2");   
    }, 1200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").addClass("mountain-3");   
    }, 2400);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").addClass("mountain-4");   
    },3600);
```

I don't understand why`setInterval()` does not work on this code, but prior to a few days ago I had barely used jQuery at all. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, where are you using `setInterval()` in the shared code..? o.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) method by returning the class names to switch from the callback option as shown below:

```js
$("body").addClass("foo mountain-1 bar");

setInterval(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass(function(index, className) {
    var s = className.split("mountain-")[1],
      n = s.slice(0, 1);
    return "mountain-" + n + " mountain-" + (n > 3 ? 1 : ++n);
  });
}, 600);
```

```css
.mountain-1 {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.mountain-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}
.mountain-3 {
  background: royalblue;
}
.mountain-4 {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").addClass("mountain-1");
setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").removeClass().addClass("mountain-2");   
}, 1200);
setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").removeClass().addClass("mountain-3");   
}, 2400);
setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").removeClass().addClass("mountain-4");   
},3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cycle this continuously, you can use something like this:

```
function rotateClassNames(selector, base, num, t) {
    var i = 0;
    var lastClass = "nothing";

    setInterval(function() {
        var index = (i++ % num) + 1;
        var nextClass = base + index;
        $(selector).removeClass(lastClass).addClass(nextClass);
        lastClass = nextClass;
    }, t);
}

rotateClassNames(document.body, "mountain-", 4, 600);
```

This uses one `setInterval()` function to rotate the class name, removing the previous class name and adding a new one.  The number at the end of the class name is cycled by using a common trick `i % 4` to make sure an incremented number is always within a range.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your setInterval code it's hard to say, but I imagine the problem is that your setInterval 'intervals' were stepping on each other since you basically start them all at the same time.  It would likely work but you'd have to stagger their start times.

If you want it to go forever you might try this addition to Abruzzi's answer:

```
$("body").addClass("mountain-1");
setTimeout(back1, 1200);

function back1(){
    $("body").removeClass().addClass("mountain-2");
    setTimeout(back2, 1200);
}
function back2(){
    $("body").removeClass().addClass("mountain-3");
    setTimeout(back3, 1200);
}
function back3(){
    $("body").removeClass().addClass("mountain-4");
    setTimeout(back1, 1200);
}
```